# stl TR1 features documentation for gcc

Tags: c++, stl, documentation, tr1

The gcc support for the language features of C++11 is well documented at http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html. However TR1 specifies several data-structures and algorithms that must (should?) be supported by compilers (e.g. `tuple`, `bind` ...).

*Note: Some of them rely on specific language features (`tuple` relies on variadic templates[>= gcc 4.3]) so they wont be available in gcc versions that do not yet support said feature, but they are not necessarily supported by the first gcc version that does support said feature.*

Is there a similar listing for the gcc support of TR1 features like for the language features?

*Note: I'm trying to compile a list of C++11 features and want to include the first gcc version you can use for each individual feature, so it's not enough for me to known that my current version does the trick (which I could test easily).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TR1 is not part of the C++ standard and support for TR1 is not required of any C++ compiler. The TR1 versions of features included in C++11, such as tuple and bind, do not use new C++11 language features because TR1 specified library features for C++03 compilers. For example, TR1 tuple does not use variadic templates and TR1 bind does not use perfect forwarding.

Also, there were some changes to TR1 features before they were adopted into the standard so code using TR1 may be different from code using C++11. For example there were name changes (E.g., `uniform_int` -> `uniform_int_distribution`) and removed portions (E.g., the facility for binding random engines to distributions was removed in favor of the more general bind facility)

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any comprehensive documentation for TR1 support in stdllibc++. If you're compiling a list of C++11 features you might not want to include TR1 at all. If you want to include TR1 anyway, remember that TR1 support could precede support for the language features required by the C++11 version of that feature.

Comment: Thanks, that sheds some light.